# Why this simple linked list program does not function properly?

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is a simple singly linked list program which I'm trying to make using class in C++.
Below is the program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>
class Node
{
  int data;
  Node *next;// to store the address of next node
  public:
    void Insert(Node*, int);
    void Print(Node*);
    bool isPalindrome(Node*);
};
void Node:: Insert(Node *head, int info)
{
  Node *temp;
  temp = new Node;
  temp->data = info;
  temp->next = NULL;
  // check if the head node is empty
  // if yes then copy address of new node(temp) into head;
  if(head == NULL)
  {
    head = temp;
  }
  Node *temp2;// for traversing upto the last node
  temp2 = head;
  while(temp2->next != NULL)
    temp2 = temp2->next;
  temp2->next = temp;// assigned the address of new node at the end of the list
}
void Node:: Print(Node *head)
{
  if(head == NULL)
  {
    std::cout<<"\n The Linked list is empty "<<std::endl;
    return ;
  }
  else
  {
    while(head != NULL)
    {
      std::cout<<" "<<head->data;
      head = head->next;
    }
  }
}
int main()
{
  Node obj;
  Node * head;
  head = NULL;

  int choice, info;
  while(1)
  {
    std::cout<<"\n Enter your choice : \n";
    std::cout<<"\n 1. Insert Element \n 2. Print Element \n 3. EXIT \n: ";
    std::cin>>choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
      case 1:
        std::cout<<"\n Enter a element  : ";
        std::cin>>info;
        obj.Insert(head, info);
        break;
      case 2:
        obj.Print(head);
        break;
      case 3:
        exit(0);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Problem with this program:

output instance:

```
 Enter your choice : 

 1. Insert Element 
 2. Print Element 
 3. EXIT 
: 1

 Enter a element  : 1

 Enter your choice : 

 1. Insert Element 
 2. Print Element 
 3. EXIT 
: 1

 Enter a element  : 2

 Enter your choice : 

 1. Insert Element 
 2. Print Element 
 3. EXIT 
: 2

 The Linked list is empty 

 Enter your choice : 

 1. Insert Element 
 2. Print Element 
 3. EXIT
```

While printing the linked list it shows: The Linked list is empty. Why?

Here in main():

```
Node obj;// this I have create to call member functions of the class.
  Node * head;
  head = NULL;
```

And what happens when `Node *head;` is executed? does the implicit constructor of class gets called?

Answer (score 0):

In `main` you are not updating the value of head - you are passing it in as a value to `Insert`. Change `Insert` to be:

```
void Node::Insert(Node *&head, int info)
```

Here `head` is passed in as a reference and therefore will be updated.

Comment: this doesn't work. you can add few more lines to your answer

Comment: Does the value of `head` change. I think that the problem is in your Insert. But then again your code is not OOD

Answer (score 0):

```
Node obj;// this I have create to call member functions of the class.
```

This created an instance of a Node.

```
Node * head;
```

From an execution point of view, this line kinda doesn't do anything. But you have a variable that may or may not point to a Node in the future.

```
head = NULL;
```

You've now set that variable to NULL, the standard way of saying it doesn't point to anything.

The variable head, inside the scope of main, is then never assigned a value. It is still NULL when you call print...

Comment: what if i made the `head` as static?

Comment: I don't think that would achieve what you want, you would then only be able to create/manage a single list. Each list should have its own head, but any nodes in the list do not need to be aware of their head. This is an argument for having a list class that manages the head and nodes.